# I need to Fetch Unique Record from master and with its repeated record in detail

Tags: sql, join, unique, master-detail

Hello Stackoverflow i am facing problem in join records from master and detail table
using Sql Query

Master Table is Represented By Following Data

[image: 001002JV 00009/0521 001002JV 00010/0521 001002JV 00011/0521]

I Have Data in Detail Table

[image]

What I need in output is

[image]

What i tried is

I need sql select query to get the result shown above

```
SELECT distinct(master.voucherkey), detail.Amount  FROM master ,detail
```

where master.voucherkey = detail.voucherkey

i.e. repeated voucherkey once and unique record many time thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the tables together rather than trying to select from both:

```sql
SELECT master.voucherkey, detail.Amount
FROM master
LEFT JOIN detail
ON master.voucherkey = detail.voucherkey
```

SQL cannot return merged rows like the picture.